# Блокировать кнопку submit при четвертом нажатии

Tags: php, html

Всем доброго времени суток! Вот Вам мой первый вопрос: есть кнопка `submit`. Нужно сделать так, если на неё 3 раза уже нажимали, то 4 раз не смогли, т.е блокировать кнопку.
Если что не поняли, могу объяснить подробнее.

Comment: мне кажется это делается на javascript, а не php

Comment: Ну а Вы нечем не сможете помочь?)

Comment: submit это надпись на кнопке или <input type="submit"... />?

Comment: <input type="submit"> да вот это?

Comment: вопрос, при жмаканье на конопку выполняется какое либо действие? с перегрузкой страницы? AJAX?

Comment: да выполняется действие!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может так:

```
<button type="submit" onclick="this.disabled = true; this.innerHTML='in progress'">click me</button>
```

Comment: при обновлении опять! можно сессию поставить ??

Comment: @anonymous_911_: Сажайте куку или генерируйте сессию с ID, которую временно сажайте в базу, что даст возможность отслеживать и отображать кнопку как `disabled`. Но учитывайте то факт, что это визуально, потому что на стороне клиента можно творить что угодно и ваш GET или POST запрос можно сгенерировать помимо вашей формы.
В конце концов, в принимающем скрипте не принимайте данные от того, у кого уже сессия "засветилась" на нажатии кнопки. Это тогда спасет от повторного `submit`-а. И т.д.

Comment: вы ему так мозг вынесли)

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант можно использовать localStorage.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sample</title>
    <script>
        function OnLoad() {
            var subm_btn = document.getElementById("subm_btn");

            subm_btn.onclick = function() {
                localStorage["submiting"]++;
            }

            if( localStorage.getItem("submiting") === null ) {
                localStorage.setItem("submiting", 0);
            } else if (localStorage["submiting"] >= 3) {
                subm_btn.disabled = true;
            }
        };

        window.onload = OnLoad;
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="get">
        <input id="subm_btn" type="submit" value="Кнопка" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: а можно сделать чтобы через например через 10 мин опять разблокировался??